# Retry and max attemps with state machine

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'm trying to make a state machine in which I want to build a retry and max attemps feature. Let me explain, so far I have this:[image]

From SAVED, I want to go to VALIDATED, although if there is an error, it has to go to AWAITING_VALIDATION state. After 3 minutes, try again to VALIDATED state.

1. Did I have correctly set up retry mechanism?
2. After 3 attemps, I want to go back to SAVED state (and pause state machine). Is it possible to do that in a fancy waty (e.g using spring state machine) or do I have to do this manually using some kind of a cache?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do these things with different machine configurations but having said that, this is such a clearly presented guestion that I wanted to spend some time on it.

You are close and you missed some things(I'd say tricks) to make this happen. Answer is to use `extended state variables` to add memory into a machine. These variables are usually used to limit number of needed stated to represent what machine needs to do. You need 3 loops and you could probably create more states to represent each loop and transition(with specific guards) to those as needed. However this will simply explode state configuration if you need more loops like 10 or 20 or 100+.

I created an example in [ssm-sample3](https://github.com/jvalkeal/randomstuff/tree/master/ssm-sample3) which is showing how `extended state variables` and different `guards` and `actions` can be used to drive this specific flow.

Unfortunately there is a bug in a current `1.1.1.RELEASE` which prevents you to directly transition from a `AWAITING_VALIDATION` into `HAS_ERROR` junction and loop until you pause into `VALID` using an anonymous transition having a guard(that's why sample has a dummy `TMP` state which is not needed with `1.2.x`).

This is probably something I'd like to add as an example or faq to our ref docs.

Lemmy know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I'll have a look today and come back to you

Comment: Which version of Papyrus have you been using? There is a few things I can't see, all labels set on transitions typically. I'm using Papyrus 2.0.1

Comment: This was with papyrus 1.1.4. 2.0.0 also gets external transition name directly from Trigger->SignalEvent->Signal. With 2.0.1 it doesn't and you need to manually give transition a name. Thought internal transition gets that name from Signal so go figure. Indeed noticed this yesterday when I tried 2.0.1 as 1.1.4/2.0.0 has a NPE bug if internal transition has an effect(fixed in 2.0.1).

Comment: It doesn't affect processing of an uml file but is a bit annoying when using papyrus designer.

Comment: I'd stick to the code so far, I'll have a better understanding this way

Comment: Now you know our state machine. Our project looks like Persist sample, we might have 500 active record (state != CLOSED). Our priorities is that it has to be "fast" and keep it simple. First, I was thinking using the exact same procedure than Persist example: using one state machine for all records. But I realised it can't be done this way due to this "retry/max attemps" feature (it won't work since it has to restart the state machine). Unless you know a trick, we might have to create on state machine per record: we are worried about performance doing this way

Comment: Yeah, timers are problematic with persistence as you don't have those machines running anymore. Keeping all machines running is then creating upper-limit as every machine will take some resources and if you ramp up, eventually you'll run out of mem. I really don't have any good answers for this right now.